# Cannot retrieve data from firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have stored data into the firebase real time database, but unable to retrieve a set of data from the database.. below i have attached a pic which shows the skeleton of my firebase database

Tell me how i will retrieve status data from database..

Sorry i changed my database structure like below..

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCQSD.png)

[After clicking the status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6ZLe.png)

Comment: Where i pushed this status string from another activity using another firebase database instance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the screen-shot is coorect and the structure is `Firebase-root -> messages -> status`, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference statusRef = rootRef.child("status");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String status = ds.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
statusRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: I your code exact as mine? Please save a JSON file from your Firebase console and post it here. Because i think the screen-shot is not correct.

Comment: I cannot see a JSON file. It's only a picture. Please post the JSON file or another correct image. The above code should work if the structure is as in your picture.

Comment: Hii.. i have changed my database structure.. see my new edited structure and please let me know hw will i retrieve data from that..

Comment: That's very different from the first one. Please click on + sign, to see the details inside that children.